# qApp Not Set and I don't know why

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, qt4

I am having some trouble with my Qt application. It looks like my qApp is uninitialized and I don't understand why. Below is a code snippet which demonstrates the problem.

```
class F3DApp : public QEnsQtApp
{
    Q_OBJECT
.
.
}

class  QEnsQtApp : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
.
.
}


F3DApp::F3DApp(int& argc, char** argv)
:   QEnsQtApp(argc, argv),

QEnsQtApp::QEnsQtApp( int &argc, char **argv)
      :QApplication(argc, argv)
```

Based on this structure, it seems like my qApp (as defined in qapplication.h, static_cast(QCoreApplication::instance()) should be set when I construct a F3DApp. However, it isn't as is shown below:

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv, char* envp[])
{ 
    F3DApp lapp(argc, argv);
    F3DApp* app = &lapp; 
    QApplication *a = dynamic_cast<QApplication *> (app); // Good
    QApplication *b = qApp;  // Nothing?
}
```

This is actually causing problems inside my QPixmap.  I'm getting a

> qFatal("QPixmap: Must construct a QApplication before a
>   QPaintDevice");

I've google'd this problem with QPixmap (inside it's qt_pixmap_thread_test()), and it doesn't look like I am statically constructing one before my qApp is actually initialized, which seems to be the common problem. Here is how I am making a SplashScreen:

```
SplashScreen::SplashScreen(QString guiVersion, QString guiVersionDate)
:   QSplashScreen(QPixmap(":/images/splash.png")),
    m_guiVersion(guiVersion),
    m_guiVersionDate(guiVersionDate)
{ 
}
```

Then from main, AFTER I made my F3DApp:

```
SplashScreen* splash = new SplashScreen(F3DApp::getVersionInfo(), 
   F3DApp::getAppDate());
```

This used to work fine when class F3DApp : public QApplication. I may simply move all F3DApp functionality into QEnsQtApp as a work-around, but I do not like sweeping problems under the rug because I'm ignorant. I'd rather not be ignorant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to dynamic cast from the derived class (F3DApp) to the base class (QApplication)?

Comment: I don't. It was just to show that I already have a QApplication but it seems like the Qt global qApp is not being set correctly. It would be weird if I was using it like that, instead of just using it.

Comment: The variable names in your main function look a bit confused. You use `c`, `parg`, and `qApp` without declaring and defining them.

Comment: Sorry, I was copying argv and argc but did not include that code. I'll make it more clear.

Comment: qApp is globally defined by qt.

Comment: Just to rule something out: Are you by chance mixing a debug build with release Qt (or vice versa)?

Comment: @Andre, I hope not. I will try building my project in release mode to see if that works. 

Looking at my "Additional Dependencies" in VS2008 SEEMS like everything statically linked is debug. Do you know of a way I can actually check? I looked using "Dependency Walker" and all my dynamically linked in have "CV" listed under Symbols.

Comment: Do `app`, `qApp` and `QApplication::instance()` point to the same location?

Comment: @Brian I have had problems with my applications combining Vtk and Qt, where Vtk in release had "GUI support" compiled in with debug Qt, while I was building against release Qt. This DID show up in Dependency Walker: It showed QtCore4.dll AND QtCore4d.dll, QtGui4.dll AND QtGui4d.dll, etc.

Comment: @Andre - You were right! I sorted by name, and QTOPENGL4.DLL was right next to QTOPENGLD4.DLL!! The same for QTCORE4.DLL and QTCORED4.DLL! I must have missed these (or selected the wrong executable) when I looked the first time! Let's see if this solves my problem. Thanks Andre.

Comment: Yup, after building a release build, this solved the problem. I'm going to try and straighten out by build process a bit and figure out where everything is coming from. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again Andre!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++-instantiated QApplication not visible by PyQt4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743509/c-instantiated-qapplication-not-visible-by-pyqt4)