# C++-instantiated QApplication not visible by PyQt4

Tags: c++, python, qt, dll, pyqt4

I have a C++/Qt application which loads a plugin (.dll/.so) using QPluginLoader facilities.
This plugin is basically an embedded python interpreter which allows to inspect Qt objects in the main application via the PyQt4 module.

Problem is the command PyQt4.QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance(), executed from the plugged-in python interpreter, returns None even though the QCoreApplication instance has been created by the C++ application.

This is only on windows in debug mode.

On linux or on release mode on windows, the command PyQt4.QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance() correctly returns the QCoreApplication instance that was created by the C++ application.

Following is some minimalist code showing the problem.

When compiled in release mode:

```
$ ./a.out
1+1
2
import PyQt4
import PyQt4.QtCore
PyQt4.QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
<PyQt4.QtCore.QCoreApplication object at 0x00C69198>
```

=> Ok

When compiled in debug mode:

```
$ ./a.out
import PyQt4
import PyQt4.QtCore
PyQt4.QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
```

=> Not ok (returned None)

**File main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QPluginLoader>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

        QPluginLoader loader("plugin.dll");
        loader.setLoadHints(QLibrary::ResolveAllSymbolsHint | QLibrary::ExportExternalSymbolsHint);
        loader.load();
        if(!loader.isLoaded()) {
                qDebug() << loader.errorString();
                return 1;
        }
        (void)loader.instance();

        return app.exec();
}
```

**File plugin.h**

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_H
#define PLUGIN_H

#include <QObject>
#include <Python.h>

class Plugin : public QObject
{
public:
        Plugin();
        ~Plugin();

private:
        PyThreadState *m_ts;
};

class InterpInput : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
public:
        InterpInput(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { }
public slots:
        void monitorInput();
signals:
        void done();
        void inputReady();
};

class InterpOutput : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
public:
        InterpOutput(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { }
public slots:
        void processLine();
public:
        PyThreadState *m_ts;
};

#endif
```

**File plugin.cpp**

```
#include "plugin.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QtPlugin>
#include <QPluginLoader>

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(Plugin, Plugin)

Plugin::Plugin()
{
        Py_Initialize();
        PyEval_InitThreads();

        InterpInput *in = new InterpInput();
        InterpOutput *out = new InterpOutput(this);
        in->connect(in, SIGNAL(inputReady()), out, SLOT(processLine()));
        in->connect(in, SIGNAL(done()), QCoreApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));

        QThread *thr = new QThread(this);
        in->moveToThread(thr);
        thr->connect(thr, SIGNAL(started()), in, SLOT(monitorInput()));

        m_ts = PyEval_SaveThread();
        out->m_ts = m_ts;

        thr->start();
}

Plugin::~Plugin()
{
        PyEval_RestoreThread(m_ts);
        Py_Finalize();
}

void InterpInput::monitorInput()
{
        PyGILState_STATE gstate;
        gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

        int ret = PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nimport code\nic = code.InteractiveConsole()");
        assert(ret == 0);
        while(true) {
                ret = PyRun_SimpleString("line = ic.raw_input()");
                if(ret) { break; }
                inputReady();
        }
        done();

        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
}

void InterpOutput::processLine()
{
        PyEval_RestoreThread(m_ts);
        int ret = PyRun_SimpleString("ic.push(line)");
        PyRun_SimpleString("sys.stdout.flush()");
        PyRun_SimpleString("sys.stderr.flush()");
        (void)PyEval_SaveThread();
        assert(ret == 0);
}
```

**File Makefile**

```
MOC=/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/moc
GCC=/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe
FLAGS=-Ic:/Qt/4.8.4/include -Ic:/Qt/4.8.4/include/QtCore -Lc:/Qt/4.8.4/lib -Lc:/Qt/4.8.4/bin -lQtCore4 -Lc:/Python27/libs -lpython27 -Ic:/Python27/include -DQT_NO_DEBUG
#FLAGS=-Ic:/Qt/4.8.4/include -Ic:/Qt/4.8.4/include/QtCore -Lc:/Qt/4.8.4/bin -lQtCored4 -Lc:/Python27/libs -lpython27 -Ic:/Python27/include -g
LIBFLAGS=-shared

all:
        $(MOC) plugin.h > plugin_moc.cpp
        $(GCC) -o a.out main.cpp $(FLAGS)
        $(GCC) -o plugin.dll $(LIBFLAGS) plugin.cpp plugin_moc.cpp $(FLAGS)
```

Comment: Did you try a workaround like passing the Qapp instance to your plugin from your main code while loading/initializing it?

Comment: More or less. There are indeed workarounds to get the QCoreApplication instance. But the underlying problem, which I did not mention yet, is that some operations which require a QApplication cannot be performed from PyQt (like QPixmap creation) if it can't see the QApplication instance by itself. Those operations could be wrapped from C++ to python in a custom module but that would duplicate what PyQt is supposed to do.

Comment: The problems happens only in debug mode. In release mode it's fine.

Comment: Could it be that (CoreApplication) symbols have slightly different names between (debug) Qt libraries and (non debug) PyQt4 module, which would make the "C++ QCoreApplication" not visible by PyQt4?

Comment: probably the explanation is that the debug version of the plugin links to QtCore4d.dll whereas PyQt4 links to QtCore4.dll, hence two different QtCore libraries referenced separately by the app+plugin and PyQt4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is the following.

In debug version, the C++ application and plugin link to debug Qt libraries (QtCored4.dll, etc.)
Whereas the installed PyQt4 modules (QtCore.pyd, etc.) link to release Qt libraries (QtCore4.dll, etc.)

It follows that the C++ application, and the PyQt4 module, each see a QCoreApplication instance but each see a different one, which lives in a different library (respectively the debug, and the release, version of the Qt library).

It follows that the instance living in the PyQt4 module is not initialized when the C++ application is initialized, and is thus null.

This is verified by compiling the PyQt4 modules specifying that they should be linked to the debug Qt libraries: the problem then disappears as the debug-mode C++ application and the PyQt4 modules link to the same Qt library.